# Initialization of multiple members using multiple return value

Tags: c++, c++17, multiple-return-values

Since C++17 I can do

```
std::pair<int, double> init () {
    return std::make_pair (1, 1.2);
}

void foo () {
    const auto [x, y] = init ();
    std::cout << x << " " << y << "\n";
}
```

That is cool, but is there any way I can initialize multiple members at once?
I mean:

```
struct X {
    X () : [x, y] {read_from_file_all_values ()} {}

    std::pair<int, double> read_from_file_all_values () {
        // open file, read all values, return all
        return std::make_pair (1, 1.2);
    }

    const int x;
    const double y;
};
```

I know, this does not work because of the syntax. I also know that I could store all the values in the appropriate `std::pair` member inside `X` and make getters which overload the ugly `std::get<N> ()` syntax, but is there any way I can initialize multiple members with single `init()` function? Since those members are const I can not do this in constructor's body.

Comment: How do you want to store the values? Your struct provides an ``int x`` and a ``double y``. Do you want to access a single pair per construction of ``X`` or do you want to access a pairs when constructing a single ``X``?

Comment: I want to store them separately, so like it is `x` and `y` but initialization of both to be done by one single function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not using structured binding, but you could have a private constructor taking in a std::pair and init the consts. Then have your default constructor delegate to this constructor with the result of your function.